# Google Cloud KVM Networking issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos7, kvm

We are testing KVM with Virtualizor in Google Cloud and are having trouble with networking. I am using IP forwarding to allow each VPS to have a separate external IP address. Everything works fine with the master server - we are able to create VMs, but the external IPs aren't forwarding correctly (or at least I can't SSH to any of the VMs). I'm thinking it's an issue with network bridging, but after following Google's guides I can't seem to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to flush your ip tables, flushing iptables disable your firewall. you should only do this if you want to start over configuring your firewall

1. First set the default policies:

- sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
- sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
- sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

2. Nex flush all tables and chains, and delete non-default chains:

- sudo iptables -t nat -F
- sudo iptables -t mangle -F
- sudo iptables -F
- sudo iptables -X